# How is it possible to create directories inside your application directory in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I've tried to create a directory inside my app's directory and got the following error:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “Some” in the folder “97391D11-283C-49FA-9A2B-8F8E2BBD89EE”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/97391D11-283C-49FA-9A2B-8F8E2BBD89EE/Some/, NSUnderlyingError=0x2819c2df0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}: file VocalTraineriOS/VocalTrainerApp.swift, line 37

Here is my code:

```
try! FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Some/", withIntermediateDirectories: true)
```

Comment: You have to get the *home directory* (which is actually the Documents directory) with [url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407693-url) of FileManager

Comment: You cannot create folders within the application directory. But what kinds of files are these? Something downloaded from the internet or some other file that can easily be recreated later? Then caches folder is probably correct so that the system can recover that storage should device space run low. If some support files that are needed for correct functioning of the app, then application support directory is right. Or is it some externally facing file, in which case documents folder makes sense.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html or https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/204/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating a folder inside the `.documentDirectory` like following.

```
do {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let someFolderURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Some")
    try fileManager.createDirectory(at: someFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    print(someFolderURL)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Documents directory URL has this format -

```
"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FB12D808-9054-4799-9C69-115ACD805A24/Documents/"
```

Comment: No, please, the string path related API is outdated and discouraged in Swift.

Comment: Thanks @vadian for the suggestion. I have updated the answer to use `URL` based api.

Comment: And I would not assume that the “Documents” folder is the correct location, either. It depends entirely upon what sort of files are going in these directories.